# Any ideas regarding sending a HTML form with a flash file attachment to server?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, flash, uploading

My development continues and I have moved forward much to my surprise in Flash and JS/HTML.

I have a question for those that have more experience.

I have a web application that consists of members and I want them to be able to send a voice recording to one another. I developed a flash voice recorder that lets the user record a message, play it back, then attach it to the message form much like a email you can attach a file and it will be in the memory until the user hits 'send'. The adding of a voice recording to the message is optional.

My question is, I have the html form and in the lower corner of the form lies my flash recorder. What would be the best strategy so that I can:

Once the user presses send, the recorder checks to see if there was any recording.

If there was no recording, send the message via AJAX normally.

If there WAS a recording,  send the message like before and also have flash attach the data with it.

I have been searching and I find online many flash uploaders, flash forms etc..

I guess what I want is that the message be HTML for those users that don't want to send a recording or cannot for some reason use flash. In otherwords the message would be a combination of data from an HTML form and data (if any) from the flash in one shot, or the best way.

But if the recorder is active then have it attached to the POST along with the message in a smooth way.

I imagine that this involves some logic and sending JS calls to the Flash then back but I am not sure of how would be the best approach to this. Can someone guide me or if you know of any good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's going to be easy for you to extract the data from the SWF and send it as part of the same POST. Your best bet is to follow the following logic on submit:

1. Make a JS call to the SWF to see if it has a recording. If not, send a normal AJAX (or synchronous) post with just the text.
2. If the SWF has a recording, make a JS call to it asking it to upload the recording. This call should include a unique message key that will be sent with the recording. The SWF uploads the file asynchronously to a special URI.
3. Send the text via AJAX or synchronous POST along with the unique message key and indicate with a flag or specific POST URI that it has an associated recording.
4. Server-side, when you receive a recording or a text with an associated recording, wait until you have both halves of the message before sending it to the recipient.

That logic doesn't include error handling or details on the data uploading from Flash, but you seem to have those parts under control.